# FPDF Exporting MySql to PDF

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I have this error fetching MySql table to PDF using FPDF.

It shows only 3 columns in portrait format where I am passing general query which should display all the columns.

I need an expert advice that how to resolve this.

My code is:

```
    <?php
    require_once("dbcontroller.php");
    $db_handle = new DBController();
    $result = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT * FROM icard");
    $header = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM       
    `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='blog_samples' AND  
    `TABLE_NAME`='icard'");

    require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);      
    foreach($header as $heading) {
    foreach($heading as $column_heading)
    $pdf->Cell(90,12,$column_heading,1);
    }
    foreach($result as $row) {
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);   
    $pdf->Ln();
    foreach($row as $column)
    $pdf->Cell(90,12,$column,1);
    }
    $pdf->Output();
    ?>
```

When I am running this script, it only fetches 3 columns. I have 10 columns which need to be fetched - how can I do it?

If you have any idea then help me

Comment: Does your code only fetch three of the ten columns or does the output PDF just show three of them, because the other seven are outside the page box instead of being put into a new column or a new page?

Comment: yes my code is about to fetch only three of ten columns.